# Changing System Color without Flashing a rom

Tags: nexus-7

Is there any way on my nexus 7 running jelly bean 4.2.2 to change the blue line that appears in the settings menu, notification bar, etc... to a green that is similar to this site's logo?

Comment: Are you rooted? If not, you won't be able to change anything like that.

Comment: No I'm not I guess I'll have to get on that then

Comment: And once having completed that, check [UOT Kitchen](http://uot.dakra.lt/) for theming stuff (where your color question belongs to).